# Dynamic array of objects - difference between initialisation methods

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I need to create a dynamic array of node objects in a function that performs some logic I will not delve into.
This function will be called multiple times consecutively for a different number of nodes (num. of nodes increments until it surpasses a million nodes).

At first I was initialising the array the following way:

```
node** heaps = new node*[arraySize];

for (int i=0; i < arraySize; i++)
  heaps[i] = nullptr;
```

However, since this function is called a large number of times, the for loop will slow down my program (I need the function to be in the order of logn, but this for loop at the beginning already makes it in the order of n).

I then saw another way of initializing a dynamic array as below:

```
node** heaps = new node*[arraySize]();
```

My program seems to work the same with just the above line, however, I'm not really sure what the difference between both methods is, and whether it really improves performance (as I can't identify a big performance difference).

Can anyone explain?

Comment: Use std::vector.

Comment: Ok, you are not allowed to use std::vector: YAIT (yet another incompetent teacher).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra "()" you are asking about is called an initializer. It is optional unless the type you provide is auto, in which case the type will be deduced from the initializer you provide.

In your first example your node pointers are default-initialized, which means their values are indeterminate. They could point at anything.

In your second example, your node pointers are value-initialized, which means they are all null pointers.

The end result is the same either way. The second example relies on your implementation to provide zero-initialized pointers for you, but I'd be surprised if it weren't as quick or faster than your for loop. When it comes to performance, always measure.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new

Comment: Thank you for that! I'll make sure to take a better look at the documentation as I'm still relatively new to C++

Answer (score 0):

Using `()` will <s>default initialize</s> value initialize the array. There would be minimal performance benefit over the loop, because it does the same job. However, if there is a performance hit because of that, then you will have to look elsewhere in your code/algorithm to find out if there is anything that can be moved to a *not so warm code path*.

If you have to use a dynamic array, use `std::vector<node*>` or `std::array<node*,N>` if you know `N` at compile time.

Or even better, use modern C++ facilities:

`using node_ptr = std::unique_ptr<node>;
std::vector<node_ptr> heaps;`

Comment: This is wrong. The `()` causes _value_ initialization, not _default_ initialization and that is not the same behavior for an array of pointers.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to make use of vectors (assignment requirements). I appreciate the answer though

Comment: He makes a good point about C++11 features. I would argue your code would probably still be improved by using an array of unique_ptrs. You can even avoid the dynamic array allocation by passing in the array size as a function argument, but you risk a stack overflow if you're talking about millions of nodes.

Comment: @tweej, sorry, my bad. Fixed from `default` to `value`.